# Upgrade F# Interactive to F#6.0

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

How can F# Interactive running from within VS Code be upgraded (v5.0 to v6.0)? The SDK is installed and when I type "dotnet fsi" from the command prompt in C:\Program Files\dotnet\ F#6.0 Interactive starts but not from VS Code, how come?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check if you have a "global.json" file somewhere in your project path. If present, the dotnet version is determined by the sdk entry in that file.

Comment: Thing is, with F# Interactive I don't have a project file but rather executing a script, where would this file then be placed?

Comment: Ok, your advice worked, just had to figure out what was the current active directory and place global.json there!